# How to write Play Framework service shell to let it start running on startup

Tags: linux, scala, shell, playframework

I'm currently working on play2.4 and using `activator dist`.
`activator dist` would produce a start script and works perfectly. but I do not know how can I make it running on server's startup?

I wrote a shell file which calls the shell file produced by `activator dist` though it works if I call it directly but it doesnt as a `chkconfig`'s service.

my current `/etc/init.d/` shell file

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 99 10

PORT=80
APP_DIR=application dir here
APP_SHELL= shell file name here

#{APP_DIR}${APP_SHELL} -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
```

where am I doing wrong? or maybe there is better way to let play project working on server's startup?

P.S
I'm using centos as a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explained here: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#The-Native-Packager

using `activator dist` is equivalent to invoking the `universal:packageBin`.
So enabling `enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)` in sbt plugins. 
Than `rpm:packageBin` should create a installable rpm package wiht upstart script.

Comment: building `rpm` file end up requiring linux machine though, its definitely one of the simplest solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script:
https://gist.github.com/Technowise/47f71f1b2c128d1f2759d4027341f4dc

Native packager described by Hüseyin Zengin may be used if you are only running a single server on 9000 always. Otherwise, I guess you'd have to run custom script like above.